# How to return values from a database table in raw format and not in the collection format?

Tags: eloquent

So, I'm creating a project for my class in `Laravel` where users will get notified by the other users that they are following but i'm finding it hard to query the data.

This is my code:

```
use App\followus;
```

> Blockquote

```
$follow=followus::select('followerid')->where('followingid',auth()->user()- 
 >id)->get();

$followers=User::where('id',$follow)->get();
```

`$follow` is being returned as **Collections**, which is causing `$followers` to return **Null**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrrau.jpg)

When I add `first()` to `$follow`, such as:

```
$follow=followus::select('followerid')->where('followingid',auth()->user()->id)->first()->followerid;
```

Its returning the raw value which is then working but in this case I can only notify a single user out of the entire list which I dont want.

Can someone please help me with this as I am not very familiar with mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a collection of **followerid** values, you need to use **pluck()** method instead of **get()**:

```
$followerIds=followus::where('followingid',auth()->user()->id)->pluck('followerid');
```

In order to later filter by a list of IDs, you need to use **whereIn()** instead of **where()**:

```
$followers=User::whereIn('id',$followerIds)->get();
```